# Clicking on ImageView which acts as a like button selects multiple ImageViews instead of ONLY the one I select

Tags: java, android

I have an `ImageView` which acts as a like button and when a user clicks on it, it changes to a different `ImageView` which indicates that that comment was liked. The problem is that when I click on one, more than one gets selected. Let's say that there are 6 comments in the list and I "like" the 4th comment, other ones get "liked" also which shouldn't happen. The only one that should be getting "liked" is the one I click on. How can I fix this?

**CommentAdapter**

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        mFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        final Comment comment = mCommentList.get(position);

        holder.comment.setText(comment.getComment());

        commentLike(comment.getCommentid(), holder.commentLike);
        commentDislike(comment.getCommentid(), holder.commentDislike);

        holder.commentLike.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (holder.commentLike.getTag().equals("like") && holder.commentDislike.getTag().equals("dislike")) {
                likeComment(comment.getCommentid(), mPostId, comment.getPublisher());
            } else if (holder.commentLike.getTag().equals("like") && holder.commentDislike.getTag().equals("disliked")) {
                likeComment(comment.getCommentid(), mPostId, comment.getPublisher());
                removeDislike(comment.getCommentid());
            } else {
                removeLike(comment.getPublisher(), comment.getCommentid());
            }
        });

        holder.commentDislike.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (holder.commentDislike.getTag().equals("dislike") && holder.commentLike.getTag().equals("like")) {
                dislikeComment(comment.getCommentid());
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Don't be mean", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (holder.commentDislike.getTag().equals("dislike") && holder.commentLike.getTag().equals("liked")) {
                dislikeComment(comment.getCommentid());
                removeLike(comment.getPublisher(), comment.getCommentid());
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Don't be mean", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                removeDislike(comment.getCommentid());
            }
        });

        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(v -> {
            if (comment.getPublisher().equals(mFirebaseUser.getUid())) {
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Would you like to delete this comment?");
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "No", (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss());
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes", (dialog, which) -> {
                    deleteCommentNotification(mPostId, comment.getCommentid());
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Comments Liked").child(comment.getCommentid()).setValue(null);
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Comments Disliked").child(comment.getCommentid()).setValue(null);
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Responses").child(comment.getCommentid()).setValue(null);
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Your comment has been deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                });
                alertDialog.show();
            }
            return true;
        });

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CircleImageView image_profile;
        TextView username, comment, commentLikesNumber, commentDislikesNumber, commentResponseNumber, timestamp;
        ImageView commentLike, commentDislike, iconComment;

        ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            commentLike = itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon_thumb_up_grey);
            commentDislike = itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon_thumb_down_grey);
        }
    }

    private void commentLike(final String commentid, final ImageView imageView) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comments Liked").child(commentid);
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (mFirebaseUser != null)
                    if (dataSnapshot.child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).exists()) {
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_blue);
                        imageView.setTag("liked");
                    } else {
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_grey);
                        imageView.setTag("like");
                    }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void commentDislike(final String commentid, final ImageView imageView) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comments Disliked").child(commentid);
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (mFirebaseUser != null)
                    if (dataSnapshot.child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).exists()) {
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_down_blue);
                        imageView.setTag("disliked");
                    } else {
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_down_grey);
                        imageView.setTag("dislike");
                    }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

**CommentsActivity**

```
    private void readComments() {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Comments").child(mPostId);
        ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                Comment comment = dataSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class);
                try {
                    comment.setComment(decrypt(comment.getComment(), mPassword));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mCommentList.add(comment);
                keysList.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                mCommentAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mCommentList.size() - 1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                int index = keysList.indexOf(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                mCommentList.remove(index);
                keysList.remove(index);
                mCommentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };

        reference.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your code and found that you are making mistake by fetching data from firebase by creating methods in the adapter and calling it from onBindViewHolder.
I am currently working with firebase realtime database and I had faced the same problem like you before 3 months and the solution i have used is working fine.
You should have to use asyncTask inside recycler view adapter. Please have a look at my code, this may help you.
Feel free to ask me if you need any help regarding android and firebase

ChooserAdapter.java

```
public class ChooserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<Bean> list;
    Context context;

    public ChooserAdapter(ArrayList<DoctorList> list, Context context) {
        this.listFiltered = list;
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }



    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.bean = list.get(position);
        holder.asyncTask = new AsyncTask(holder,holder.bean.getId());
        holder.asyncTask.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public ArrayList<List> adapterList() {
        return list;
    }

    public List getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.txtTitle)
        TextView txtTitle;
        AsyncTask asyncTask;
        Bean bean;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }


    static class AsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        String Id;
        DatabaseReference dbRef;

        AsyncTask(ViewHolder viewHolder, String Id) {
            this.viewHolder = viewHolder;
            this.Id = Id;
            dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("FcmNode");
            dbRef.keepSynced(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            if (!isCancelled())
                dbRef.orderByChild("Id").equalTo(Id).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            String name = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                            viewHolder.txtTitle.setText(name);
                            viewHolder.txtTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }
                });
            return "";
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String data) {
            super.onPostExecute(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey buddy, thanks for your response. So could you explain why it's not correct the way that I am doing it writing methods in the Adapter class? Haven't been programming for that long, but I have seen a lot of people do it this way, and thus have opted for this way as well.

Comment: @JMB When adapter is start binding all view it will not wait for your method response and result of position 1 might bind to view of position 2, so to prevent this data mismatch i have suggested to use async task because its stick with your view holder so there is no change in mismatch and you will get what you want. Thank you.

Comment: Can we chat so you can help me make this adjustment in my code?

Comment: Sure we can my skype id is parth_darji_812, send me a request on this.